# How to compile a Go package on Windows?

Tags: go, window, cross-compiling

The documentation is all for Mac OS X and Linux, and I wish to know how to compile a Go package on the Windows platform. On Windows, I do not know how to write the make file and which tool to use to make it.

It seems that there is not a tool named make or go make to use with the installation file of Go development tools.

Comment: You'll have to get it for Windows. Try [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: @Hassan You mean that I have to build a similar GNU environment on Windows? Like the function of cygwin so that I can use the make tool?

Comment: Yes. But if you already have cygwin you could just use it instead. I believe make is available for cygwin, but I haven't tried it. I do know MinGW is simple and easy to use. Either way, once you get some compilers and make installed, you should just open a terminal, cd to Go's directory, then type "make", and it will compile (hopefully).

Comment: @Hassan I have no reasons that I hate the GNU.

Comment: @Hassan: Go doesn't need make files anymore. See peterSO's answer

Answer (score 10):

Compiling a Go package on Windows is like compiling a Go package on Linux or Mac OS X. Use the [`go build`](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) command. There is no make file.

Here are some instructions.

[Getting Started](http://golang.org/doc/install)

[How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

[Compile packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Compile_packages_and_dependencies)

Comment: There are still plenty of go peojects on github that do have make files. Often the release page would have windows executable but no instructions on how to compile on Windows, only on mac/linux with `make`

Answer (score 5):

There are no more Makefiles needed in Go, so the `make` tool isn't necessary. You also do not need cygwin.

If you do not seem to have a valid `go` command in your windows shell, then try following the official docs on [installing Go for windows](http://golang.org/doc/install#windows)

> **Zip archive**
>
> Extract the zip file to the directory of your choice (we suggest
>   c:\Go).
>
> If you chose a directory other than c:\Go, you must set the GOROOT
>   environment variable to your chosen path.
>
> Add the bin subdirectory of your Go root (for example, c:\Go\bin) to
>   to your PATH environment variable.
>
> **MSI installer (experimental)**
>
> Open the MSI file and follow the prompts to install the Go tools. By
>   default, the installer puts the Go distribution in c:\Go.
>
> The installer should put the c:\Go\bin directory in your PATH
>   environment variable. You may need to restart any open command prompts
>   for the change to take effect.
>
> **Setting environment variables under Windows**
>
> Under Windows, you may set environment variables through the
>   "Environment Variables" button on the "Advanced" tab of the "System"
>   control panel. Some versions of Windows provide this control panel
>   through the "Advanced System Settings" option inside the "System"
>   control panel.

The last section is important. Your windows PATH environment variable needs to have `C:\Go\bin`, so that you will have `go` in your path.

Answer (score 4):

from: ***Golang windows, a complete setup guide***, http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/07/golang-windows-complete-setup-guide.html

**1) download ZIP**

> Get the latest code from: http://golang.org/dl/

**2) extract ZIP**

> Extract zip to example C:\local\dev\go

**3) create a gopath directory,**

> Gopath is where third parties will be stored. Example if you will
>   execute a "go get github.com/somelib", this library will be stored in
>   gopath. Create a c:\local\dev\gopath

**4) set the environmental variables**

> open System Properties->Advanced->Environmental Variables

```
GOROOT=C:\local\dev\go
GOBIN=%GOROOT%\bin
GOPATH=c:\local\dev\gopath
```

**5) add your gobin to PATH**

> append C:\local\dev\go\bin to PATH

**6) test**

6.1) create the path "C:\local\dev\gopath\src\myfirstproject"

6.2) create the main.go file "C:\local\dev\gopath\src\myfirstproject\main.go"

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hi foobar")
}
```

6.2) you can now build the project anywhere example,

6.2.1) open cmd.exe

6.2.2) cd c:\temp

6.2.3) go build myfirstproject

6.2.4) run myfirstproject.exe

**7) get a few libraries**

7.1) you can download some free git, svn, and hg for windows

7.2) once you have them you can now do "go get -u github.com/somelib"

**8) get an IDE**

> download liteide

**congrats!**

Comment: Thanks. I would like to compile for linux, being on windows. Am I able to do so? Seems that I can't find a way to set GOOS and GOARCH.